# Suitelet to trigger a client script and redirect back to the Suitelet on save

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

EDIT 1: The code client has been edited to include the resolve url suggestion

This is a follow on from [Trigger a client script on a button clicked on a Suitelet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70729005/trigger-a-client-script-on-a-button-clicked-on-a-suitelet)

That was answered and now I am getting stuck with another part of the script.
I have posted this on the [Netsuite Community](https://community.oracle.com/netsuite/discussion/comment/16787161#Comment_16787161) too though the response I have received there is making me more confused.

Apologies in advance if I have the StackOverflow posting etiquette/rules wrong in terms of follow up posting or cross posting.

Scenario:
There is a Suitelet with a button which results in a custom record page being loaded in edit mode.
Field values are set on the custom record using the client script that is triggered when the button on the suitelet is clicked.

[image: Suitelet]

The custom record

[image: Custom record]

Everything is working as expected until it gets to the function saveRecord part of the client script.

I am trying to get the page to redirect back to the suitelet after the record is saved though cannot get this to work.

EDIT: Working version of the code:Suitelet:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/search"], function (ui, search) {
    function getCiSetup() {
        //create a saved search of all custom records
        var customrecord_nsts_ci_setupSearchObj = search.create({
            type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
            filters: [],
            columns: [
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_admin_email",
                    label: "Administrator Emails",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl",
                    label: "Invoice Details Saved Search",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search",
                    label: "Invoice Summary Saved Search",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_type",
                    label: "Invoice Type",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_layout",
                    label: "Default CI Layout",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_duedate",
                    label: "Due Date",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_email_sender",
                    label: "Email Sender",
                }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "custrecord_nsts_ci_email_template",
                    label: "Email Template",
                }),
            ],
        })

        return customrecord_nsts_ci_setupSearchObj
    }

    var exports = {}

    function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method === "GET") {
            var form = ui.createForm({
                title: "Consolidated Invoicing Type",
            })
            // form.clientScriptModulePath =
            //   "SuiteScripts/sdf_ignore/Consolidated Invoice Client Script.js";
            //internal id of client script
            form.clientScriptFileId = 8378
            //add buttons corresponding to the different set up options

            form.addButton({
                id: "recurring",
                label: "Recurring",
                functionName: "executeRecurring",
            })

            form.addButton({
                id: "ping",
                label: "Ping",
                functionName: "executePing",
            })

            var sublist = form.addSublist({
                id: "custpage_ci_setup",
                type: ui.SublistType.LIST,
                label: "Consolidated Invoice Set Up",
            })

            sublist.addField({
                id: "custpage_invoice_dtl",
                label: "Invoice Details",
                type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            })

            sublist.addField({
                id: "custpage_invoice_summry",
                label: "Invoice Summary",
                type: ui.FieldType.TEXT,
            })
            var htmlBody = ""
            htmlBody += "<html>"
            htmlBody += "<head>"
            htmlBody += "</head>"
            htmlBody += "<body>"

            htmlBody += ""

            htmlBody += "</body></html>"

            form.addField({
                id: "custpage_html",
                label: "html",
                type: ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
            }).defaultValue = htmlBody
            var ciSetup = getCiSetup()
            var i = 0

            ciSetup.run().each(function (result) {
                log.debug("result", result)
                var invoiceSummary = result.getText("custrecord_nsts_ci_search")
                var invoiceDetail = result.getText("custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl")
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id: "custpage_invoice_dtl",
                    line: i,
                    value: invoiceDetail,
                })
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id: "custpage_invoice_summry",
                    line: i,
                    value: invoiceSummary,
                })
                i++
                return true
            })

            context.response.writePage(form)
        } else if ((context.response.method = "POST")) {
            log.debug({
                title: "request method type",
                details: "suitelet is posting",
            })
        }
    }
    exports.onRequest = onRequest
    return exports
})
```

[image: suitelet]
Client Script:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
 define(["N/record", "N/runtime", "N/url", "N/log", "N/ui/dialog"], function (
    record,

    runtime,
    url,
    log,
    dialog
) {
    /**
     * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
     */

    function pageInit(context) {}

    function executeRecurring(context) {
        var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript()
        var recordType = scriptObj.getParameter("custscript_ci_suitelet_record")
        //the url for custom record form which has the settings being set by the suitelet. Record type and record id will need to be adjusted for instance of NS
        var pageUrl =
            "https:<accountid>>.app.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=436&id=1&e=T"

        var url = new URL(pageUrl)
        //Add additional code
        window.location.href = url

        var objRecord = record.load({
            type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
            id: 1,
            isDynamic: true,
        })
        //INVOICE SUMMARY SAVED SEARCH * //value field relates to the internal id of the saved search that will be set
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search",
            value: 2079,
        })
        //INVOICE DETAILS SAVED SEARCH  //value field relates to the internal id of the saved search that will be set
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl",
            value: 2078,
        })
        //DEFAULT CI LAYOUT * 
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_layout",
            value: 1,
        })

        objRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false,
        })

    //onscreen pop up to indicate values have been set
        dialog.alert({
            title: "done",
            message: "completed running",
        })
        //the url corresponds to the suitelet page(where the user enters the value). The internal id is for the suitelet script and the deployment id relates to the deployment of the suitelet script.
        window.location.assign(
            "https://<account>.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=1123&deploy=1&compid=<accountid>>&whence="
        )

        //look into window.close for the newly opened window
    }
//the values relate to the internal ids for the drop down fields set on the custom record form
    var customSubmit = function returnFields(context) {
        record.submitFields.promise({
            type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
            id: 1,
            values: {
                custrecord_nsts_ci_layout: 1,
                custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl: 2078,
                custrecord_nsts_ci_search: 2079,
            },
        })
    }
    
//the same function as above though the values correspond tot he user selecting 'one off' button
    function executeOneOff(context) {
        var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript()
        var recordType = scriptObj.getParameter("custscript_ci_suitelet_record")
        var pageUrl =
            "https://<account>.app.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=436&id=1&e=T"

        var url = new URL(pageUrl)
        //Add additional code
        window.location.href = url

        var objRecord = record.load({
            type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
            id: 1,
            isDynamic: true,
        })
        //INVOICE SUMMARY SAVED SEARCH *
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search",
            value: 1669,
        })
        //INVOICE DETAILS SAVED SEARCH
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl",
            value: 1668,
        })
        //DEFAULT CI LAYOUT *
        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_layout",
            value: 1,
        })

        objRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false,
        })

        // window.open(redirectUrl);
        // window.location.assign(
        //   "https://tstdrv2531816.app.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=143&id=1&e=f"
        // );

        window.location.assign(
            "https://<account>.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=1123&deploy=1&compid=<account>>&whence="
        )

        //look into window.close for the newly opened window
    }

    var customSubmit = function returnFields(context) {
        record.submitFields.promise({
            type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
            id: 1,
            values: {
                custrecord_nsts_ci_layout: 1,
                custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl: 1669,
                custrecord_nsts_ci_search: 1668,
            },
        })
    }
    

    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        executeRecurring: executeRecurring,
        executeoneOff: executeOneOff,
        customSubmit: customSubmit,

        // saveRecord: saveRecord,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var suiteletURL = "https://tstdrv.app.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=143&id=1&e=f";
window.open(suiteletURL, '_self', false);
```

If this doesn't work, you can also use `url.resolveScript` API under `N/url` module in your ClientScript.

```
var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
   scriptId: 'custom_script',
   deploymentId: 'custom_script_deployment'
});

window.open(suiteletURL, '_self', false);
```

Also, instead of adding this to `SaveRecord` in ClientScript, you can add this towards the end of your `executeRecurring` function.

Give this a try. Let me know in comments below.

**EDIT -**

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/runtime", "N/url", "N/log"], function (
  record,

  runtime,
  url,
  log
) {
  /**
   * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
   */

  function pageInit(context) {}

  function executeRecurring(context) {
    var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
    var recordType = scriptObj.getParameter("custscript_ci_suitelet_record");
    var pageUrl =
  "https://tstdrv.app.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=143&id=1&e=T";

    var url = new URL(pageUrl);
    //Add additional code
    window.location.href = url;

    var objRecord = record.load({
      type: "customrecord_nsts_ci_setup",
      id: 1,
      isDynamic: true,
    });
    //INVOICE SUMMARY SAVED SEARCH *
    objRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search",
      value: 456,
    });
    //INVOICE DETAILS SAVED SEARCH
    objRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_search_dtl",
      value: 452,
    });
    //DEFAULT CI LAYOUT *
    objRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: "custrecord_nsts_ci_layout",
      value: 1,
    });

    objRecord.save({
      enableSourcing: true,
      ignoreMandatoryFields: false,
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = null;

    var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: "customscript_ci_suitelet",
      deploymentId: "customdeploy_ci_suitelet",
    });

    window.open(suiteletURL, "_self", false);
  }

  return {
    pageInit: pageInit,
    executeRecurring: executeRecurring
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sayeesh

I have edited the original post to add the code I have tried. 

It doesn't reload the page or open the original suitelet

Comment: Hey @Lefemmenikita, I have editted my answer. Just copy paste the ClientScript and test once. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Sayeesh. I have copied and pasted your client script exactly. However, it still does not redirect or refresh the page.